# Reset DSum back to zero

Tags: ms-access-2013, cumulative-sum

I am wondering whether it is possible to reset DSum back to 0 after it reaches 1,000,000.

Technically, the DSum will calculate for me the running total for Total Count and will then reset back to 0 when Total Count is 1,000,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use *modulus*:

```
YourLimitedNumber = YourLargeNumberFromDSum Mod 10 ^ 6
```

or directly in the *ControlSource*:

```
=DSum(...) Mod 10 ^ 6
```